# Command line ios program

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode4.6

I have build a C++ library for iOS, and now I want to write an illustration program to show how to use this library. A very simple one might be a command line program. However, I cannot find any command line application option with XCode 4.6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a project template for "command-line application for iOS", only for Mac OS X (see the new project dialog: select OS X -> Application -> Command Line Tool).

You can however create a very minimal iOS app - the Single View iOS project template might be a good starting point. You could demonstrate use of your library in this simple app by hooking up a few buttons and/or text entry fields to the library.

Answer (score 1):

You will use a UITextView, and create your own virtual CLI. So in your program, Shen you get to this step animate in that view and open the keyboard.